# How can I use Python to walk through files in directories and output a pandas data frame given certain constraints?

Tags: python, pandas, os.walk

So I'm using Pyhton, and I have a parent directory, with two child directories, in turn containing many directories, each with three files. I want to take the third file (which is a .CSV file) of each of these directories, and parse them together into a pandas dataframe. This is the code I have this far

```
import os

rootdir ='C:\\Dir\\Dir\\Dir\\root(parent)dir'
# os.listdir(rootdir)
# os.getcwd()

filelist = os.listdir(rootdir)
# file_count = len(filelist)

def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        # if files.startswith('C74'):
            for name in files:
                r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r

filelist = list_files(rootdir)
```

Now with "filelist" I get all file paths contained in all directories as strings. Now I need to find:
1. The file names that begin with three specific letters (for example funtest, in this case the first letters being fun)
2. Take every third file, and construct a pandas dataframe from that, so that I can proceed to perform data analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC we can do this much easier using a recursive function from pathlib :

```
    from pathlib import Path
    csv = [f for f in Path(r'parent_dir').rglob('*C74*.csv')]
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv])
```

if you want to subset your list again you could do

```
subset_list = [x for x in csv if 'abc' in x.stem]
```

#### Test

```
[x for x in csv if 'abc' in x.stem]
out : ['C74_abc.csv', 'abc_C74.csv']
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Do you know if it is possible to give another condition that sorts through the name? For example if I only want the files containing "C74" as well as"abc"? This would solve the need for having to pick out every third file, in my case. I tried putting another .rglob right after, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: you can do another list comp @Zygos check answer

Comment: Would it be possible to do this right after the first recursive function, but before the concat? I tried doing just that, and got an error: "TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable". I would like to do this since every individual file needs to be cleaned before concated, ideally.

Comment: Actually I found an answer: I just added XYZ in the rglob function: ```csv = [f for f in Path(r'P:\\APO\\Data\\GOB data\\LaserData').rglob('*C 72*XYZ*.csv')]```
Thank you for your help!